# Print value from Golang custom strcu

Tags: go, goland

I am new to Golang. I have below code,
Can someone please help to Print Only ID from the custom created struct?

```
type Currency struct {
    ID        uint         `db:"id" json:"id"`
    Name      string       `db:"name" json:"name"`
    Code      string       `db:"code" json:"code"`
    CreatedAt sql.NullTime `db:"createdAt" json:"createdAt"`
    UpdatedAt sql.NullTime `db:"updatedAt" json:"updatedAt"`
}

type temp struct {
    Currency map[string]Currency
}

func GetCurrencies(db *sqlx.DB) ([]Currency, error) {
    sqlStatement := `SELECT * FROM "Currencies"`
    var currencyRows []Currency
    err := db.Select(&currencyRows, sqlStatement)
    return currencyRows, err
}

func PrintC(db *sqlx.DB) {

    Currencies, _ := GetCurrencies(db)
    stores := []temp{}
    for _, currency := range Currencies {
        store := temp{
            Currency: map[string]Currency{
                currency.Name: {
                    ID:        currency.ID,
                    Name:      currency.Name,
                    Code:      currency.Code,
                    CreatedAt: currency.CreatedAt,
                    UpdatedAt: currency.UpdatedAt,
                },
            },
        }
        stores = append(stores, store)
    }

  fmt.Println(stores)

}
```

Current Output:

```
[{map[Ethereum:{2 Ethereum ETH {2022-02-03 14:10:58.264 +0000 UTC true} {2022-02-03 14:10:58.264 +0000 UTC true}}]} {map[Bitcoin:{1 Bitcoin BTC {2022-02-03 14:10:59.471 +0000 UTC true} {2022-02-03 14:10:59.471 +0000 UTC true}}]}]
```

Expected Output:

// PRINT ONLY ETHEREUM ID
// PRINT ONLY BITCOIN ID

Comment: can you explain clearly what output do you expect? is it just the IDs (which is just numbers) or a slice containing IDs? or something else?
it would be better if you write the expected output like the current output's format

Answer (score 1):

You can implement Stringer interface and define the way how would you like to print out your struct.
https://go.dev/tour/methods/17

Answer (score 0):

This snippet bellow implements the **Stringer** interface which is required by the **fmt** package. Basically the **fmt** package look for this interface to print values.

```
func (cr Currency) String() string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("%v", cr.ID)
}
```